# Could I make a QuoteLineItem custom field that finds the name of the Product2 associated with it

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-field, quotelineitem

Title basically explains all of my question. Links and/or examples would be very helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a custom field on quoteLineItem. And populate the field with product2name by using a simple trigger . Plz refer to the following trigger example :

```
trigger testTrigger on quoteLineItem( before insert){

    list<quotelineitem> plist = new list<quotelineitem>();
    for(quotelineitem q : [select id, product2.name,product2id, customfield__c  from quotelineitem where id =:trigger.new]){
        q.customfield__c = q.product2.name;
        plist.add(q);
    }
    update plist;
    }
```

Here, the field "customfield__c" will be populated with the associated product name in the quoteLineItem every time a quoteLineItem is inserted.
Let me know if this helps.

Comment: and why not use a cross object formula field?

Comment: how is this trigger called? I have no knowledge in Apex triggers and feel semi foolish for asking this

Comment: Go to setup >develop > Apex Triggers > new > Add this trigger  and save. This will automatically run when you will insert any new quotelineitem. Let me know if you have any furthur issues

Comment: I have no idea how to write the test class for the trigger, any help?

Comment: follow this link to know about test classes http://www.sfdc99.com/2013/05/14/how-to-write-a-test-class/